# updateDescription.updatedFields in Change Event From mongoDB is null

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I am trying to watch the updates on a specific field `status` in MongoDB change stream.

From the [Change Event documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/) page, a change stream will output this document:

```
{
   _id : { <BSON Object> },
   "operationType" : "<operation>",
   "fullDocument" : { <document> },
   "ns" : {
      "db" : "<database>",
      "coll" : "<collection"
   },
   "documentKey" : { "_id" : <ObjectId> },
   "updateDescription" : {
      "updatedFields" : { <document> },
      "removedFields" : [ "<field>", ... ]
   }
}
```

I am always getting all the fields but getting `updateDescription.updatedFields` as null.

Here is the Java code I'm using

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection");
List<Bson> pipeline = Collections.singletonList(Aggregates.match(Filters.and(
        Document.parse("{'fullDocument.status':  { $in: [ 'DONE','ERROR'] }}"),
        Filters.exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.status",true),
        Filters.in("operationType", ("replace")))));

MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor = collection.watch(pipeline).iterator();
```

I am using these dependencies with the project

```
<mongo.java.driver>3.6.3</mongo.java.driver>

<spring.data.mongo.version>1.10.10.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem that I was testing using "edit document" on Robo.
The "edit document" does not update one field, it replaces all the document with a new one having the same id.

Comment: Great catch. This also happens in Studio 3T.

Comment: You can also watch on fullDocument changes: `{$match:{'fullDocument.someProp': 'aValue'}}`